# Lag variable is not working when using stock market data from Quandl

Tags: r

I am running the following script:

```
library(Quandl)
df <- Quandl(c("WIKI/AAPL"))
str(df)
head(df[,c(1,2)])
df$lagOpen <- lag(df$Open, 1, na.pad=TRUE)
head(df[,c(1,2,14)])
```

but as you can see from my results below, my lagged variable is the same like the original one.

```
head(df[,c(1,2)])

    Date      Open
 1 2016-12-22 116.35
 2 2016-12-21 116.80
 3 2016-12-20 116.74
 4 2016-12-19 115.80
 5 2016-12-16 116.47
 6 2016-12-15 115.38
```

I tried sorting my data to see if this could solve the problem

```
df <- df[order(df$Date),]
head(df[,c(1,2)])
df$lagOpen <- lag(df$Open, 1, na.pad=TRUE)
head(df[,c(1,2,14)])
```

but I have the same problem

```
head(df[,c(1,2,14)])

     Date       Open    lagOpen
9087 1980-12-12 28.75   28.75
9086 1980-12-15 27.38   27.38
9085 1980-12-16 25.37   25.37
9084 1980-12-17 25.87   25.87
9083 1980-12-18 26.63   26.63
9082 1980-12-19 28.25   28.25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lag` works with time series, so you can ask `Quandl` to return a `type="xts"`:

```
library(Quandl)
df <- Quandl(c("WIKI/AAPL"), type="xts")
df$lagOpen <- lag(df$Open)
head(df[,c("Open","lagOpen")])

            Open lagOpen
1980-12-12 28.75      NA
1980-12-15 27.38   28.75
1980-12-16 25.37   27.38
1980-12-17 25.87   25.37
1980-12-18 26.63   25.87
1980-12-19 28.25   26.63
```

Comment: Is there anything I can do to tell R that my data set is a time series, so I can use the lag function? Thank you for your help!

Comment: yes you can use `ts()` but then it's no a data.frame anymore... May be you can add details about what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: I am trying to calculate the daily return or rate of change as (Open-lagOpen)/lagOpen. For example, based on the results you produced the return for 2016-12-22 would be (116.35-116.80)/116.80

Comment: When I am trying to calculate the return using the above formula I get the following error message: Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : dims [product 9088] do not match the length of object [0]. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: After executing the code in my answer, I get no error with `df$return <- (df$Open-df$lagOpen)/df$lagOpen`